# Form action contents returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form method=“post” id=“foo” action=“foo/bar”>…</form>
```

I’m trying to store the content of the action attribute in a variable and display it like this:

```
var action = $(“foo").attr(“action”); 
alert(action);
```

But the alert is returning ‘undefined’. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using normal quotes ?

Comment: It also matters *when* your script runs.  Make sure it's being run after the form has been declared or use the document ready event to run it.

Comment: it has to be $('#foo'), since the # signs defines an ID selector in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `#` when you're using id selector and change `“` by double quotes  and it will work check snippet bellow :

```
var action = $("#foo").attr("action");
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
    var action = $("#foo").attr("action"); 
    alert(action);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="foo" action="foo/bar">…</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix your quotes:

```
<form method="post" id="foo" action="foo/bar">…</form>
```

Then you should get the form action:

```
var action = $("#foo").attr("action");
```

Also, please sure all the DOM elements are loaded before trying to access them, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var action = $("#foo").attr("action");
    alert(action);
});
```